# ASP.NET Razor ViewModel property is modified somewhere

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have an extremely simple Controller + View

```
public ActionResult Edit(string username)
{
    return View(ComponentFactory.GetAdapter<IUserListAdapter>().Get(username));
}
```

and

```
@model BAP.Models.UserList
@using GrmanIT.Utils.Web
@using BAP.Models
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Globale Benutzer</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Model.UserName
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bundesland)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bundesland, new SelectList((IEnumerable<BAP.Models.Bundesland>)ViewData["BundeslandList"], "Value", "Text"))
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="@LocalizationHelper.LocalizedLiteral("Save").ToString()" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink(LocalizationHelper.LocalizedLiteral("BackToList").ToString(), "Index")
</div>
@Model.UserName
```

this is by far the simplest controller and view we have in our MVC4 application, BUT - it does something weird:
I get the TextBox, which is created with *@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)* prefilled with the *UserId* of the model instead of the *UserName*

I debugged it and it and there as always the correct value in *UserName* and *UserId*. You can also see, that I added *@Model.UserName* twice within the View to see if it get also correctly rendered, and yes, it prints the UserName and not the ID.

I've also checked references to the *UserName*-property and didn't find any, which would modify it. My question is - do you have any idea, where the code could be modified or how could if find it out?

It happens only on this one controller on this one action (out of ~25 controllers and ~200 actions)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was AGAIN the ModelState - as you can see in the code above - the parameter to the function is called "username" but it's actually the userId. And since there is already the parameter username, it is stored in the ModelState and when I call

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

it takes the value from the ModelState (where actually the UserId is stored under the name of the action-parameter)

So the solution would be, either to call ModelState.Clear() or rather, rename the parameter to represent the actual value.